# Execution of stored procedure using spring's SimpleJdbcCall not giving output

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

This is My DAO Class, Which has a datasource that connects to Database, and retursn the following :

```
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG CallMetaDataContext:380 - Using declared parameter for: PRICETOLERANCE_CSR
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall:313 - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call Z_GETPRICETOLERANCEREJECTS(?)}]
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall:289 - SqlCall for procedure [Z_GETPRICETOLERANCEREJECTS] compiled
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall:395 - The following parameters are used for call {call Z_GETPRICETOLERANCEREJECTS(?)} with {}
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall:398 - 1: priceTolerance_csr, SQL type -10, type name null, parameter class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter]
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:1062 - Calling stored procedure [{call Z_GETPRICETOLERANCEREJECTS(?)}]
2017-03-28 09:49:42 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-03-28 09:49:43 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:1136 - CallableStatement.execute() returned 'false'
2017-03-28 09:49:43 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:1137 - CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
2017-03-28 09:49:43 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-03-28 09:49:43 INFO  GenerateReportDaoImpl:59 - [null]
```

The `GenerateReportDaoImpl`

```
@Component
public class GenerateReportDaoImpl {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenerateReportDaoImpl.class);
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
    }

    public String getReportEmailFromDB(String lookupCode){
        String sql = "select lookup_description from ussco_lookup_table where lookup_code = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{lookupCode},String.class);
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getRecordsFromDatabase(String procedureName) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,procedureName);
            Map<String, Object> out =  jdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName)
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("priceTolerance_csr", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new PriceToleranceFailureRptRowMapper() )).execute();


        logger.log(Level.INFO,out.values());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the Price Tolerance Failure Report Row MApper

Comment: Silly question, perhaps: does the stored procedure actually return a `NULL` value?  Take Java and JDBC out of the question for the time being and try calling the stored procedure in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or something similar to see what it actually returns.

Comment: yes, i ran my stored proc in SQL developer, it returns results, But when i ran it through spring, i am facing issues. wwith the above code

Comment: Well that's odd.  I tried a number of things in order to reproduce your problem but the only way I could do it was if the stored procedure actually returned `NULL`.  The only other suggestion I have is that you have a buggy version of the Spring libraries (should such a thing exist) or are perhaps missing one or more of them: I'm using spring-beans, spring-core, spring-jdbc and spring-tx version 4.2.2, spring-data-oracle 1.2.1 and spring-dao 2.0.8.